# Spree goes back to default config till app restarted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I have a spree store that is resetting itself back to the default config settings after a seemingly random amount of time (e.g title goes from 'shop' to 'spree demo site'). It then directs people to https (paypal only so no https) and all payment gateway / mail info gone.

The app is running on heroku cedar stack. If I push code or restart the app the settings go back to how I configured them.

I'm not sure what info to provide as I have no idea what would cause this. If anyone can help, please ask for which code files you need and I will post straight away.

To start, Gemfile is here: https://gist.github.com/3845475

The site is featured on the BBC this coming Wed (expecting the site to get hammered), so any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It seems like a strange Heroku specific problem, on such a short notice maybe you should try deploying on EC2 or Linode as a temporary solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the latest relevant branch for your version of Spree. I believe this problem was fixed as part of the fix for [Issue #1500](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/1500).